# ConEmu dissapearing of history after I run something

Tags: conemu

[image]

[image]

When I run this command it shows version only for millisecond and everything disappears. And again when I run command for to check version only then it shows properly.

Comment: Why are you talking about ConEmu? Isn't it the `ionic` problem?

Comment: No, its Microsoft problem, I got the solution in Reddit. Its related to sound mixer.